# How can I get Manage Package Id from UI

Tags: managed-package

I am not able to find package Id, can anybody help ?

Comment: It looks like the Package Id isn't available to view from the UI. You can use Workbench or Execute Anon, for example to get the Id though via a simple SOQL: SELECT Id,NamespacePrefix FROM PackageLicense

Answer (score 8):

You can get all the installed package versions in your org by using Salesforce DX CLI
Follow the following steps:

1. Set up [CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_intro.htm).
2. Authorize your org using command [sfdx force:auth:web:login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_auth.htm#cli_reference_force_auth)
3. Run the package list command and specify the user ID using -u parameter: [sfdx force:package:installed:list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm#cli_reference_install) -u .

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Open list of installed packages:
   setup -> Build -> Installed Packages
2. Click on your requested package
3. get the id from the URL:
   [image: get package id from url]